# GCS bucket migration across different organisations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We are currently planning to migrate some GCS buckets across different organisations.

After having a look at the documentation, it seems that that's something one can do between projects and buckets, but not between different organisations.

Does anyone know if that is the case or is there any other way of migrating as part of the GCP toolset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grant access to both Google Cloud projects associated with the Cloud Storage buckets you should be able to copy from one bucket to the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) program, so long as you have an account that has access to both projects / organizations, you should be able to access the resources.

The following example would copy the files between the buckets:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket1 gs://bucket2
```

You can [add a member by email](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin) to your projects here.

If all this does not work, you may need to use the API. The right forum for those types of question would be [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-storage).